# How can I reject posting in php?

Tags: php, forms, post, pdo, get

I want my PHP file not to post to the website which I wrote in action. How can I post the site if all the inputs are filled?

My index.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Form Validation</title>
    <meta name="description" content="The HTML5 Herald">
    <meta name="author" content="SitePoint">
    <style>
        #inp1{
            margin-bottom: 3px;
        }
        #first{
            margin-bottom: 20px;
        }
        #second{
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<section>
    <h1>Php Form Validation</h1>
    <div>
    <form action="post.php" method="post">
        <div id="first">
       Name: <input type="text" name="name" id="inp1" autocomplete="off"><br>
       Email: <input type="text" name="email" id="inp1" autocapitalize="off"><br>
       Password: <input type="password" name="pwd" id="inp1"><br>
       Repeat Passowrd: <input type="password" name="pwdrepeat">
        </div>
        <div id="second">
            Gender:
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">Female
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">Male
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other">Other
        </div>
        <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
        <?php
        if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
            $name = $_POST['name'];
            $email = $_POST['email'];
            $password = $_POST['pwd'];
            $passwordRe = $_POST['pwdrepeat'];
            $gender = $_POST['gender'];
            if (!empty($name) && !empty($email) && !empty($password) && !empty($passwordRe) && !empty($gender)){
                if ($password === $passwordRe){
                    echo "<p style='color:green;'>Successfully submitted!</p>";
                }else{
                    echo "<p style='color: red'>Your password is not equal to the other</p>";
                }
            }else {
                echo "<p>Please fill all the inputs</p>";
            }
        }
        ?>
    </form>
    </div>
</section>
</body>
```

I think something must be edited between PHP tags:

```
<?php
        if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
            $name = $_POST['name'];
            $email = $_POST['email'];
            $password = $_POST['pwd'];
            $passwordRe = $_POST['pwdrepeat'];
            $gender = $_POST['gender'];
            if (!empty($name) && !empty($email) && !empty($password) && !empty($passwordRe) && !empty($gender)){
                if ($password === $passwordRe){
                    echo "<p style='color:green;'>Successfully submitted!</p>";
                }else{
                    echo "<p style='color: red'>Your password is not equal to the other</p>";
                }
            }else {
                echo "<p>Please fill all the inputs</p>";
            }
        }
        ?>
```

I'm working on a Quiz-app and started PHP recently, and I don't know how I can reject posting in PHP. Stackoverflow says you must add some more details and write something about your question, but I don't have anything to write that's why now I'm writing some stuff.

Comment: Want you want is called “form validation”, do a bit of research using that keyword, you should be able to find plenty.

Comment: Ok I'll do it thx

Comment: Now I'm doing it, but every site posts the PHP file to the same file but I want to post to another site

Comment: Then you should look into _client-side_ validation.

Comment: @CBroe we both know that client-side validation is just a *comfortable addon* and a complete validation system cannot rely on it only. OP: You can handle form rendering and validation in one script, just in case when there are missing fields, re-render the form using input data (sanitize them before reusing) otherwise when everything is all right, save the form and redirect to another page i.e. *thankyou.html* with PHP's header. As Cbroe mentioned, client-side validation is good, but you should use only for making side look and fill more comfortable for the end user, not securing.

Comment: @biesior if they want to send this “to another site”, then the server-side validation should be handled by however is in charge of that site, I suppose. (Other than porting the whole sending of the data from the client side to their own server first, to then send the POST to the remote server _from there_, there isn’t much chance for the OP to do “server-side” here to begin with.)

Comment: @CBroe OP, IMHO just wants to reject form sending if it's invalid so it can be fixed by the user and re-send. That's what I'm trying to explain to him he should re-render the form with data (and probably with some error messages) handling it in the same script if a form error occurred. No need to using another *action* attribute here. Sorry, just could say it before, the form handling on the server side should be just moved to the index.php file (or to another file, but form's rendering, validation and submitting should be in one file.)

Comment: Other option is redirecting user from `post.php` to `index.php` after validation error.